# "Ich wundere mich" vs. "es wundert mich"

Tags: difference

I have seen both structures (intended, I believe, to express: "I am surprised that ..."):

- Ich wundere mich, dass ...
- es wundert mich, dass ...

Haben beide Arten, das Verb *wundern* zu verwenden, genau die gleiche Bedeutung?

Comment: That's the same difference as English *I wonder* vs *It puzzles me*. If you choose the variant with *Ich*, you put emphasis on the fact that *you* wonder.

Comment: Rather same as *I wonder* vs. *It makes me wonder* in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference goes to the *source* of the "wunder."

"Ich wundere mich," means "I am curious about..." (The wondering starts with me. You may or may not join me in wondering.)

"Es wundert mich," means, "It makes me wonder." (The event was so striking that it caused me to wonder. You probably will, too.)

Answer (score 1):

Ja, es ändert sich nichts an der Bedeutung. Die Form mit *ich* ist etwas direkter ausgedrückt, aber es liegt auf der selben Sprachebene und legt nach meinem Empfinden auch keine andere Betonung oder Bedeutung bei. Die zweite angegebene Form mag älter wirken, wird aber trotzdem heute formelhaft genauso oft verwendet und ist aktuell.